TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities' APPIUM
I'm new to Appium automation in Python, this is my first project actually.
I don't use selenium in this project.
This is my code:
`from appium import webdriver
from os import path
CUR_DIR = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
APP = path.join(CUR_DIR, 'TheApp.app.zip')
APPIUM = 'http://localhost:4723'

CAPS = {
    'platformName': 'iOS',
    'platformVersion': '17.4',
    'deviceName': 'iPhone 12 mini',
    'automationName': 'XCUITest',
    'app': APP,
}

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor=APPIUM,
    desired_capabilities=CAPS
)`

When I run the code I get
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'
I found out that DesiredCapabilities was removed and I should transform it into Options, but I don't find how to do it for Appium, only for Selenium.
What can I do?

You can use options like this:
from appium.options.ios import XCUITestOptions

CUR_DIR = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
APP = path.join(CUR_DIR, 'TheApp.app.zip')
APPIUM = 'http://localhost:4723'

CAPS = {
    'platformName': 'iOS',
    'platformVersion': '17.4',
    'deviceName': 'iPhone 12 mini',
    'automationName': 'XCUITest',
    'app': APP,
}

driver = webdriver.Remote(APPIUM, options=XCUITestOptions().load_capabilities(CAPS))

